# What’s a reliable way to remove an ended listener from an AudioBufferSourceNode?

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

I assigned a callback function to the AudioBufferSourceNode.ended property:

```
var myAudioBufferSourceNode.ended = function() {
  console.log('Playing ended.');
};
```

How do I unlisten?

Does `myAudioBufferSourceNode.ended = null` effectively unlisten across browsers?

Comment: Yup. That should work.

Comment: Doesn't it need to be `myAudioBufferSourceNode.onended = null` (onended instead of ended)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, setting an EventHandler to null is a good way to stop listening to an event.

Comment: It's a good way *if* the handler was registered with target.onevent = handler. If it was registered with addEventListener, not so much.